# Node.js doesn't create a NPM folder in /bin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed Node.js on MacOS but I can't use NPM (`command not found`) and the bin repertory only contains node.
I have installed Node.js several times but the same thing happens. I have searched for a few days without results.
Thanks!

Comment: Although the mac OS installer from NodeJS directly should contain NPM, you can use Homebrew to install NodeJS and it automatically installs NPM with it

Comment: I don't know how you installed NodeJS, but in addition to @LanceWhatley suggestion, I have also used NVM (Node Version Manager) which allows you to install multiple versions of Node and it also installs NPM as well. I've personally haven't had any kind of missing NPM issues on Mac with either installation method.